# Unrecognized manifest key 'applications'. warning for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have created my Web Extension for Firefox which uses Chrome Extension API.

But Firefox requires `application` key in `manifest.json`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

If I load the same extension for Google Chrome, Chrome warns as:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Unrecognized manifest key 'applications'.
```

Although the extension works, I am not sure if I can send a Firefox Web Extension  to Google Chrome Store with this manifest file.

I can create another project for Google Chrome but I want to keep a single folder that may work for both Firefox and Google Chrome without any warnings.

How I am suppose to fix this warning while keeping Firefox requirements?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably want to generate separate manifest files even if everything else is unchanged. After all, the docs state:

> `applications`. Only supported in Gecko.

My recommendation is a build script that copies over the files and the correct manifest for each version (or dynamically generates the correct manifest if you want fancy).

Comment: While I understand this answer, it just seems stupid to me that they don't get on the same page.  Either Google should just accept and ignore it or Firefox should do without it.

Comment: @JeffG As far as I know, it was only an issue with early versions of WebExtension support. Quoting: _"`"applications"` is not supported in Google Chrome, and is mandatory in Firefox **before Firefox 48**."_

Comment: In addition to @Xan's comment, here's the source that states, that the `applications` key is mandatory now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/WebExtensions_and_the_Add-on_ID#When_do_you_need_an_Add-on_ID

Comment: i wonder if there is a sample out there of "build scripts" that get your extensions to the right form for chrome, firefox, opera and ie

Answer (score 2):

Running 68.0b13 (64-bit), I just deleted the "applications" key and body

```
//  "applications": {
//      "gecko": {
//          "strict_min_version": "58.0a1"
//      }
//  },
```

and it works fine without it.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/WebExtensions_and_the_Add-on_ID#When_do_you_need_an_Add-on_ID) says:

> Note that the ability to develop and debug WebExtensions that don't include an ID is new in Firefox 48. If you need to use an earlier version of Firefox, then you must use the applications key to set an ID explicitly.

My interpretation of that is that the "application" key is NOT necessary for `>=` Firefox 48.

Comment: There are some APIs that still require it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/WebExtensions_and_the_Add-on_ID#When_do_you_need_an_add-on_ID

Comment: I didn't see a way to use browser.storage.sync without creating an ID during development. (I think that was the API I was having trouble with.)